# What is mysql password

Tags: php, mysql, cmd, phpmyadmin

i was trying to import a large database (only 6.26MB) into phpmyadmin using cmd.
After writing the syntax of importing the database, i've been asked to enter the password. My phpmyadmin or mysql has no password from what i know.[Screenshot of the syntax attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXNU1.png)

Can you help me to tell me which password i'm asked to enter ?

Comment: Do you know your user password ?

Comment: You're a senior developer and you're asking what your password is?

Comment: The default password is empty. Did you try to just hit enter?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the password for the account, `user`

```
mysql -u [username] -p [database name]
```

*Note: You will be asked for the password during the execution of this command*

Which in this case you have,

Username: `user`
So, you are being asked to enter the password for the MySQL account: `user`.

Comment: I figured it out ! Thanks for the suggestions. Instead of putting the name of the user i used user instead of root.